# Paramterize query without executing in rusqlite

Tags: sqlite, rust, rusqlite

I would like to generate parameterized queries using rusqlite, to be executed in a different thread. That is, I would like to parameterize a string into the final SQL statement, *before* passing it to conn.execute.

I can see that there is an "expanded_sql" function in https://github.com/rusqlite/rusqlite/blob/master/src/statement.rs#L690 -- but I am not sure whether this is the right function and/or how to use it. I don't really want to do a prepared statement, just parameterize the string.

I have also got lost in lots of problems passing a dyn ToSql between threads, which is not allowed. Working with strings of the queries seems much safer?

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Passing `dyn ToSql` between threads is not allowed because the dynamic type specification doesn't require that the concrete type be thread-safe; if you instead use `(dyn ToSql + Sync)` or `(dyn ToSql + Send)` you restrict the concrete types to those that impl `Sync` or `Send` but thereby inform the compiler that the dynamic type can be shared or sent between threads.